# Localized meta tag for search engines

Tags: html

Let say a multi-language website such as dictionary, and it supports en-us and de, and es.
Now I would indicate my website to google that all these languages are supported.
For example, if user search either `World` or `Welt`(german) or `Mundo`(spanish), google should find out the site useful.
In other word, I would have 3 metas tag as site description in all languages supported. something like following.

```
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="World: where we are living">
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Welt: wo wir leben.">
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Mundo: donde estamos viviendo.">
```

Then user would find it if he searches the `world` in many languages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela where should I post it then buddy? :D

Comment: Try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ but first analyze your problem more. What do you really wish to achieve? Are you talking about multilingual site (with each page in some language) or multilingual pages? What effect do you expect the `meta` tags to have? “Google should find out the site useful” does not really say that.

Answer (score -1):

It would be possible to accomplish this using the
`lang` attribute inside the meta-tag.
Using this, you would get a result that looks like this:
`<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" LANG="en" CONTENT="World: where we are living">`

However, I assume that in general you have different pages for different languages so you can add the metadata based on the selected language.

Comment: Do you have any evidence on Google actually caring about `lang` attributes at all or on some specific processing of multiple `<meta name=description ...>` tags? Google generally says they ignore `lang`, and the natural expectation is that only one  `<meta name=description ...>` tag per page matters (the first one or the last one), if they matter at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela so you mean I have to go for second approach? separated domains for each lang?